# Can you request expedited processing of a Canadian visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canada

Can you request for expedited processing of a Canadian visitor visa?

Answer (score 7):

There is no standard way to request expedited processing for visitor visas. You may of course include your circumstances in a letter of explanation which may or may not be considered when the immigration officer decides the priority of your file.

If a Canadian sponsor is available with urgent justifications, the sponsor can contact the office of their Member of Parliament for assistance. For certain serious humanitarian circumstances (e.g. accidental or sudden death/serious injury of a foreign national), sometimes the embassy or consulate of the foreign national's country (or their close family's country) can also be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you do not need to, it just gets expedited. This is called the CAN+ program. It's automatic https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=877&top=16

> Visa application centres will screen all applications for CAN+ eligibility. Applications that show that the applicant travelled to Canada in the last 10 years or holds a valid U.S. non-immigrant visa will be sent to the visa office for expedited processing.

and requires no specific forms https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=875&top=16

> Is there a different application form for CAN+?

> No. Simply apply for a visitor visa online or on paper.